# Windows 7 Professional wallpaper keeps disappearing

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I have a legal and activated copy of windows 7 professional. However for some reason my wallpaper keeps disappearing and defaulting to black?

I have no idea why, please help.

I have already tried doing this, but I am not running windows 7 beta...
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110612062450AALUQok

Comment: When is it doing this? during reboot?

Answer (score 1):

**I get this from time to time, I suspect its because I use BGInfo, which stores my wallpaper in the TEMP directory.**

If you're setting it via IE and/or modifying it via BGInfo or a similar utility, it may be stored in the %TEMP% directory. If you or another program are cleaning this directory out regularly, when the systems boots, it can't find the last known location of the image. Try saving the wallpaper to a specific location (like your pictures folder) and set it from windows explorer, not IE.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your graphics card for updates.
- Make sure, that nobody is connected via Teamviewer because Teamviewer
  disable your wallpaper always when a new customer is connecting to
  your computer

**or this**

yes it is called windows genuine advantage notification.
every time you set the back ground & reboots the computer it shows up.

it is the file executing named- wgatray.exe
  it is present at C:\Windows| folder. Go there & delete that file. (you can search it also )

Comment: If the installation is legit why would the author delete the file?